# Unable to play mp3 in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, audio-player

I am trying to play file from direct web link(http) but it throws exception:

> Can not create player for: Unsupported contect type

code is simple as

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer("http://c648382.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/01_Genesis_001/0001.mp3");
player.realize();
player.start();
```

here is StackTrace:

```
javax.microedition.media.MediaException: Cannot create a Player for: Unsupported content type
    at javax.microedition.media.Manager.getPlayerFromType(+13)
    at javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(+35)
    at javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(+389)
```

I am using `WTK 2.5.2` and `DefaultColorPhone` emulator

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know `2.5.2` does not support mp3. Did you try [newer versions](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/terrencebarr/archive/2008/10/goodbye_wtk_hel.html) of emulator?

Also per my recollection there is a way to programmatically find out content types supported by particular device / emulator. Check JSR 135 (MMAPI) javadocs for details if you're interested.

Comment: I don't have data about eclipse. Only heard that it is integrated with netbeans